# Partition table in AWS Glue to multiple tables with Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have JSON files in an S3 bucket that follows this schema:

```
{
    "object1" : {...},
    "arrayObjects1" : [
        {...},{...},...
    ],
    "object2" : {...},
    "arrayObjects2" : [
        {...}, {...}, ...
    ],
    "object3" " {...}, 
    "arrayObjects3" : [
        {...}, {...}, ...
    ]
}
```

I would like to create a separate table for each of the first level indices.  That would mean 6 tables in this case, one for object1, object2, etc.  Each of these can get pretty lengthy given the need for a separate table for each.

So far I've tried adding some custom classifiers to try and achieve what I'm looking for. They've looked like this:

Try 1:

```
$.object1
$.arrayObjects1
```

etc.

Try 2:

```
$.object1
$.arrayObjects1[*]
```

etc.

Running with these classifiers, I get the exact same schema for my table I had when I ran the crawler without a custom classifier. Upon further reading, I believe that these classifiers would instead limit what data actually makes it into my table instead of making a separate table for each index.

Maybe I am going about this entirely wrong, but I'd like to be able to create tables from Glue using crawlers and classifiers instead of creating tables through Athena to hopefully save on cost as the size of the data set scales up. If anyone has a recommendation that would be great.

UPDATE: I've been looking into AWS Glue Jobs and that seems to be the route to go. If anyone has experience here that would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: What I would do is the following:

1. Crawl the data in order to get the schema.
2. Create a GLUE job in which I transform the data to my liking, and split it appropriately.
3. Write the new dataframes/dynamicframes to a location.  S3, JDBC, etc.  This might be a good starting point:

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-samples/blob/master/FAQ_and_How_to.md

Comment: @Kyle Thank you! I didn't really understand the difference between DataFrames and DynamicFrames (rather naive on my part) and that article really helps